# Report server 2016 Can't load data from shared datasets

Tags: dataset, load, sqlreportingservice

We encountered error when load data from shared datasets (all) on Power Bi Report Server (march release). It seems this kind of error appear too on other Report Servers.

On Data Preview tab, when click on "Load Data", we get this error message :

> An error has occurred.
>  
>   The data set could not be processed.
>   There was a problem getting data from the Report Server Web Service.

On log, the only error we get are (it depend of way we get the dataset on the server. If saving from report builder this is the first one, if upload it from local, this is the second) :

> ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ItemNotFoundException: , Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ItemNotFoundException: The item 'xxx' cannot be found.;

OR

> Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.WrongItemTypeException: , Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.WrongItemTypeException: The operation you are attempting on item 'xxx' is not allowed for this item type.;

The account I use have all the rights, and this error appears for everyone try to load a shared dataset.

When opening it with Report Builder, it works fine, and when use with reports, it works too.

But We need to use those datasets with KPI, and when select field from dataset, we get again this error message.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that the hostname specified in the rsreportserver.config file is correct.  Should find it listed in Service section.

```
<Service>
    <Hostname>IsThisNameCorrect???</Hostname>
    <IsSchedulingService>True</IsSchedulingService>
```

Comment: Thanks MikeDes for your answer.
Unfortunately, adding <Hostname> part to <Service> has no effect.

In fact, this is when trying to load data from dataset that error appear.

Regards,

Comment: Dear Mike
I finally found the solution. You're almost in
I update this section on rsreportserver.config
 <UI>
  <ReportServerUrl>http://servername/ReportServer</ReportServerUrl>
  <PageCountMode>Estimate</PageCountMode>
 </UI>
thanks for your help